# python matplotlib BoundaryNorm mapping values equal to top boundary are mapped to set_over color

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to map values between 0.1 and 1.0 discrete colors while setting values below 0.1 and above 1 to specific colors. This should be a trivial problem it seems. Using
matplotlib.colors.SetBoundaryNorm generates a map that maps the 1.0 into the color set by set_over.

```
import matplotlib.colors as colors
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
ncolors=11
vmin = 0.1
vmax = 1.0
cmap = get_cmap('RdYlBu_r',10).copy()
cmap.set_bad(color='gray',alpha=0) # alpha =0
cmap.set_under(color='white')
cmap.set_over(color='hotpink')
#            cmap=get_cmap('RdYlBu_r').with_extremes(under='white',over='hotpink',bad='gray')
boundaries = list(np.arange(vmin, vmax, 0.1))+[vmax]

norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries, ncolors=ncolors, clip=False,extend='both')

print(norm(boundaries))

data=boundaries.copy()
data.insert(0,0)
data.append(1.5)

# make data for a test image to display 
bar=np.repeat([data],5,axis=0).repeat(5,axis=1)
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

img=plt.imshow(bar,cmap=cmap,norm=norm)
img.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
img.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal', extend='both')
plt.show()
```

[image]

If I remap the input values at 1.0 to 0.999999 it produces what I want but that seems strange. Is the documentation incorrect that "values greater and equal" to the top boundary will be mapped to the top index?